# android FilrPrivider not woorking twice

Tags: android, kotlin

The process is to create a jpg file based on the timestamp, add the uri to the list, and display it through the lisetview

the first picture is normal,but Error will be reported when the second picture is obtained

The error occurred before `Log.e("addiamge","====" )`

```
E  Writing exception to parcel
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: writing
net.qingmowan.Inspection.custom.MyFileProvider uri 
content://net.aaaa.bbb.fileprovider/my_image/inspection_16679577393117723686263338001557.jpg
from pid=30798, uid=10084 requires the provider be exported, or grantUriPermission()

  at android.content.ContentProvider.enforceWritePermissionInner(ContentProvider.java:919)
  at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.enforceWritePermission(ContentProvider.java:698)
  at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.enforceFilePermission(ContentProvider.java:669)
  at android.content.ContentProvider$Transport.openAssetFile(ContentProvider.java:493)
  at android.content.ContentProviderNative.onTransact(ContentProviderNative.java:272)
  at android.os.Binder.execTransactInternal(Binder.java:1154)
  at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:1123)
```

```kotlin
val intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
var photoURI: Uri? = null
val imageUris = LinkedList<Uri>();
val adapter = ImageAdapter(this, imageUris, layoutInflater)
val imageList = findViewById<ListView>(R.id.imageList)
imageList.adapter = adapter
 val launcher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) {
     if (it.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && photoURI != null) {
         Log.e("addiamge","====" )
         imageUris.add(photoURI!!)
         Log.e("images", imageUris.toString())
         adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
     }
 }
image.setOnClickListener {
    photoURI = getPhotoUri()
    intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI)
    launcher.launch(intent)
}
private fun getPhotoUri(): Uri? {
    val photoFile: File? = try {
        createImageFile()
    } catch (ex: IOException) {
        Log.e("获取拍照文件", "失败", ex)
        null
    }
    photoFile?.also {
        val uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(this, "net.aaa.bbb.fileprovider", it)
        return uri
    }
    return null
}
private fun createImageFile(): File {
    val storageDir: File? = getExternalFilesDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
    val timeStamp = Date()
    val file = File.createTempFile("inspection_${timeStamp.time}", ".jpg", storageDir).absoluteFile
    Log.e("file_message", String.format("name:%s, file.absolutePath))
    return file
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Every time you get a photo from the camera, you need to create a new intent and reset the action

Move the definition of intent to the clickListener

```kotlin
image.setOnClickListener {
    photoURI = getPhotoUri()
    intent1.action = MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE
    intent1.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, photoURI)
    launcher.launch(intent1)
}
```

As for why I don't know, I hope someone can supplement my answer